# Make Android Phone Call Audio go through A2DP Bluetooth Connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a sprint anycom bluetooth reciever connected to my car stereo.  I think it only supports the A2DP bluetooth profile (no hfp).

Right now the music plays through the car stereo just fine but when I get a phone call it does not.  Ideally I would like to have the phone call audio go through the stero and use the phone's microphone as if it were on speakerphone. Is this possible?

My phone is a g1 running the latest experimental release of cyanogenmod rom.

I would love a built in solution but I think the ability to do that is so non standard it wouldn't exist.  An existing marketplace app with the ability would be great, too.  I have not done any android development but I am a java developer, so a pointer on how to do it programmatically (or that it is not possible) would be great, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call recording is not yet possible on Android. See this [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117#c226).

You can record your voice from microphone, but you can not record the sound of the other party.

Comment: Are you saying that because you cannot record the incoming voice it is also not possible to have it output or redirect it to the car speakers using the a2dp profile?

Comment: Yes, at least not from the Java app.

Comment: Hi, Harpreet. Can you explain how to slove it? Thks.

Comment: Harpreet, how do you do it?